# WCF REST Service - Get parameters in UriTemplate in POST Method

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, service

I'm building a WCF REST Service which has a POST method with the url:

```
http://localhost:8888/application/list_i/{agent_name}
```

Post Parameters: username and password

Now, while I'm able to get the username and password through the type Stream, I can't get the UriTemplate to match, because it thinks agent_name is also supposed to be a post variable, whereas, it is a get variable, a part of the request URL.

The Operation Contract

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.IO

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IMobileAppService

    <OperationContract()>
    Function IndividualCases(ByVal stream As Stream) As ArrayList

End Interface
```

The Service Class

```vb
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Web

' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the class name "MobileAppService" in both code and config file together.
Public Class MobileAppService
    Implements IMobileAppService

    Dim mysqlconnection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=root; password= ; database=dattaibm;")

    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate:="/application/list_i/{agent_name}")>
    Public Function IndividualCases(ByVal stream As Stream) As ArrayList Implements IMobileAppService.IndividualCases
        Dim request As NameValueCollection = processStream(stream)
        Dim response As New ArrayList
        response.Add(New IndividualCase With {.activity_id = "00001", .customer_name = request("username")})
        response.Add(New IndividualCase With {.activity_id = "00002", .customer_name = request("password")})
        response.Add(New IndividualCase With {.activity_id = "00003", .customer_name = "00003"})
        Return response
    End Function

End Class
```

In the end, the UriTemplate isn't matching anything I ping via a Rest Client.
Can anyone help? This is my first time dabbling with WCF services.

Thanks

UPDATE:

My app.config, if need be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="MobileAppService.MobileAppService">
              <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888/" />
                </baseAddresses>
              </host>
              <endpoint address="http://localhost:8888/" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MobileAppService.IMobileAppService"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**NOTE: I'm running this as a self-hosted WCF Service in a console app.**

Comment: UPDATE: I've uploaded the project files here: http://www.files.com/shared/562b712d83153/MobileAppService.zip